# How to discover and communicate with certain interfaces in external applications

Tags: android

My application is searching for data, given various filtering parameters. This data is acquired from multiple sources (i.e. multiple sites over Internet). I want other developers to be able to implement **their own data sources**, so they could "plug" them into my application **without** any action on my part.

What is the best way to achieve that? In particular:

1. What should the external developers do to make their implementations visible to my process?
2. How do I discover such external implementations?
3. Once discovered, what can I use as an identifier for each of these implementations?
4. How to communicate with various "methods" of the external implementation.

My best guess is to use services:

1. Have external developers set up their service with intent-filter with *a specified URI*.
2. Use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)#queryIntentServices method to list all services matching *a specified URI*.
3. Use their package name as identifiers, so I can fire up intents directly at that package.
4. Believe that external developers listen and properly respond to all intents specified in my docs. I will pass them either PendingIntent or Messenger objects to get the results back.

I haven't yet tried it and I am a beginner in Android. Is this the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have external developers set up their service with intent-filter with a specified URI.
>
> Use PackageManager#queryIntentServices method to list all services matching a specified URI.

If by "URI" you mean "action", this is certainly one approach.

> Use their package name as identifiers, so I can fire up intents directly at that package.

Yes.

> Believe that external developers listen and properly respond to all intents specified in my docs. I will pass them either PendingIntent or Messenger objects to get the results back.

Those would work. I'd lean towards PendingIntent.

> Is this the proper way?

:: shrug ::

"Proper", like truth and beauty, lies in the eye of the beholder.

(and hopefully not [that beholder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beholder) -- those things were nasty)

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your approach. I might do the same thing, modulo my comments above.

Some alternatives:

- Same strategy, but have the service export a binding interface with AIDL, with your host binding to them (advantage: richer API, disadvantage: bigger pain to set up, particularly if your host is an activity)
- Plugins are `ContentProviders`, which you discover by an authority naming convention or some bootstrap method
- Plugins really communicate with you via broadcast `Intents` (works well if the predominant data flow is them pushing data to you rather than you pulling data from them)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I didn't stumble upon [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) before, I will look into it!

Comment: You wrote, "I'd lean towards PendingIntent". Currently I use Messenger, because my plugins may provide their data incrementally, in a couple of steps. Would you still lean towards PendingIntent in such case? Somehow I feel that PendingIntents are designed to be more of an one-time event, but maybe I'm wrong about it.

Comment: @wrygiel: The choice of `PendingIntent` is more personal preference than anything else. `PendingIntent` certainly can be used more than once, though it may be more tedious than `Messenger` to populate it with additional data. If `Messenger` is working for you, stick with it.